# I'm getting 403 – Forbidden: Access is denied on IIS v10 ashx files

Tags: iis-10, ashx

I'm getting  403 – Forbidden: Access is denied on IIS v10 when trying to run ashx files.

I'm using classic application pool with identity **Local System**

Can you please help?

Comment: Could you please share the sub status code for the 403 error? You could share the error snapshot here. Further, you could check that anonymous authentication is enabled. Check the website root folder has IIS_IUSRS and IUSR permission. Try to test by enabling the Directory Browsing.

Comment: I'm getting only "Status Code: 403 Forbidden" no sub code.
The anonymous authentication is enabled with the application pool identity.
If i'm uploading an aspx file to the same path I can see it. 
But ashx files no. 
I think it's something about the extension (I checked the Mapping handler) but I can't find what.

Comment: I would suggest you check the IIS logs, check the FRT logs, and Check the detailed error message. You could go to `IIS -> Error pages-> Edit features settings-> Select Detailed errors option and click OK` For testing purposes, try to give full permission to the site folder.

Comment: Thanks for updating us that the issue is resolved. I would suggest you mark the helpful suggestion as an answer to this question. It could help other community members in the future with similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you check the IIS logs, check the FRT logs, and Check the detailed error message. You could go to **IIS** > **Error pages** feature > **Edit Features Settings...** in **Actions** pane

[image]

Then, select **Detailed errors** option and click <kbd>OK</kbd> (Refer screenshot):

[image]

For testing purposes, try to give full permission to the site folder.